# How to set scale to object image in unity 3D by Code?

Tags: android, iphone, unity-game-engine

I'm a new unity 3D developer i create a button by c# code and set image to button but that image show small.
How to resize scale image ?

Answer (score 4):

If this is an `Image` Component, you use assign new `Vector3` to `Image.rectTransform.localScale`. I suggest you use `Vector3` instead of `Vector2` so that you can always use 1 as the **Z** value. The code below will scale x and y to 4 then leave z as 1.

```
public Image myImage;

void Start()
{
    myImage.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(4, 4, 1);
}
```

For `Texture2D` use the method below.

```
public Texture2D myImage;
void Start()
{
    myImage.Resize(4, 4);
    myImage.Apply();
}
```

For `Sprite`

```
public Sprite myImage;
void Start()
{
    myImage.texture.Resize(4,4);
    myImage.texture.Apply();
}
```

For `SpriteRenderer`

```
public SpriteRenderer myImage;
void Start()
{
    myImage.transform.localScale = new Vector3(4, 4, 1);
}
```

For `GUI.Button`

```
float x = 300;
float y = 300;
float width = 150;
float height = 150;

void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, y,width, height), new GUIContent(icon)))
    { 

    }

    //scale width
    width = 400;

    //scale height
    height = 400;
}
```

Comment: i use texture object @Programmer

Comment: @sony Texture2D? If you are creating a button, isn't the button's image type `Image`? The new UI uses `Image` for the buttons.... You should post your code to make your question clear.

Comment: public Texture2D icon;

 void OnGUI()
 {
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(300, 300, 150, 50), new GUIContent(icon)))
  {
  }






 }

Comment: @sony The GUI your are using is old. You need to start using the newer one. Look for another tutorial because the current one you are learning with is obsolete. http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui

Comment: Anyways the updated answer. The second answer or the last one should work. For the second answer you can just put `icon.Resize(400, 400);` then  `icon.Apply();` in the OnGUI function. It will resize. If that doesn't work, try the last answer. One of them should work for you. When you are done, delete it and start using the new UI I posted the link to.

Answer (score 1):

Scaling the UI.Button

```
var rt = this.gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rt.anchorMin = new Vector2( 0.5, 0.5 ); 
rt.anchorMax = Vector2.one;
rt.offsetMin = rt.offsetMax = Vector3.zero;
```

Or, you can just use the offsetMin/offsetMax in case you're only support one screensize. In that case offsetMin/offsetMax represents an the amount of pixels.

Comment: He's not using `UI.Button`. He is using `GUI.Button` which is the old Unity UI. Read the comment he left under my answer. Also, your code is redundant. You could have done `this.gameObject..GetComponent<RectTransform>();`